# Android contacts tables update but do not get saved to SIM

Tags: android, android-contacts, updates

I am trying to update the phone number associated with a contact on the SIM. I am able to update the Data table's row ok, but the change does not get propagated to the SIM. I dump out the Data row after it has been updated; the _ID is still the same, the phone (data1) col has the new phone number. When I powercycle the phone, the entry has the old value. The raw contact number of the contact has been incremented by 1. Any ideas on how to make the change persistent in the SIM? (Yes, I know some doc says access to SIM is not supported. But the Contacts app can do it - there must be a way for an app to update the SIM.) There may be typos - I had to (re)type the code by hand here.

Here is the code I use to update the row.

```
String rawId = "87"; // provided by caller; hardcoded here for brevity
String num = "212-222-3333";   // new phone #

ContentResolver cr = ...get actvity's resolver...

Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number, num);

String select = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID " + " = " + rawId + " and " +
    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" + 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_ITEM + "'";
String[] selectArgs = {};

cr.update(uri, cv, select, selectArgs);
```

Catch exception and other details omitted.

Thanks for any clues!